# In nano 000-default.conf (as root user) in Apache2 on EC2 Ubuntu Instance on AWS page is blank?

Tags: apache, apache2, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-aws

When I SSH into my ubuntu server on EC2 in Amazon Web Services, and I change to the root user using sudo su, I navigte to /etc/apache2/sites-available to make changes to the 000-default.conf file there.  This was working just fine, but when I nano in (using nano 000-default.conf), I am seeing just a blank page in the terminal.

When I do the same thing as just the ubuntu default user (not root), I see the file fine.  This just changed after I made a change to the file as the root user.  I can't make any more changes as the default user (it needs to be root for the permissions).  Any idea why this is happening?  Thank you.

Comment: Check the file ownership and permissions.

Comment: no matter what the permissions are you should always be able to edit a file as root.

Comment: Are you typing the file name wrong when using sudo?   If I use `sudo nano 0000-default.conf` I get a blank screen (note the extra zero in the filename).

Comment: See this post: [Is there a difference between sudo su - root and sudo -u root -H /bin/bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/is-there-a-difference-between-sudo-su-root-and-sudo-u-root-h-bin-bash)  It has been my practice to never use both together as the shell can't keep track of the environment variables in some cases.

Comment: So then another possibility is that your `/root/.bash_profile` or `/root/.bashrc` is changing the working directory.   In that case you are not editing a file in the current directory anymore with `sudo`.   Try with a full path to the file:  `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`